# Which parameters to use with FFMPEG to rectify Mars Ingenuity helicopter images?

Tags: fisheye

I know how to convert a fisheye image to equirectangular, to view it inside a 3D VR viewer as a "panorama":

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360:fisheye:equirectangular:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=0 -y output.jpg
```

- -i input file
- -vf video filter

  - v360: VR360 panorama conversion

    - fisheye: source format
    - equirectangular: destination format
    - ih_fov: input horizontal FOV
    - iv_fov: input verticalFOV
    - pitch: camera up/down orientation
  - -y Overwrite
  - Output file

Instead I would like to "rectify" the Ingenuity fisheye image, as if it was shot with a standard camera; I know about **[lensfun](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lensfun)** and **[lenscorrection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection)** parameters , but I don't undrestand which parameters I should use.

Cameras official data:

> **Navigation (NAV) Camera** has a ﬁeld-of-view (FOV) of 133 deg
> (horizontal) by 100 deg (vertical) with an average Instantaneous
> Field-of-view (IFOV) of 3.6 mRad/pixel

> **Return-to-Earth (RTE) Camera**  has a FOV of 47 deg (horizontal) by 47 deg (vertical) with
> an average IFOV of 0.26 mRad/pixel.

> The NAV camera is pointed directly towards nadir, and the RTE camera
> is pointed approximately 22 deg below the horizon, resulting in an
> overlap region between the two camera image footprints of
> approximately 30 deg × 47 deg.

Source: https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf

Full FFMPEG documentation: [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)

Ingenuity raw images: https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/index.cfm?af=REAR_HAZCAM_RIGHT

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. https://superuser.com/questions/1662721/which-parameters-to-use-with-ffmpeg-to-rectify-mars-ingenuity-helicopter-images Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: This question is weird: it is receiving upvotes everywhere I post it on SE... but at the same time it is always requested for closure and for moving somewhere else. And nobody answers.   Please can anybody answer rather than closing/commenting/moving?

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg is *not* the most appropriate tool to use for lens correction of still images.  While it may work, it is not *really* meant to be used that way.  Since you are already aware of the documentation, it's a matter of reading and applying it.

- [lensfun](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lensfun): The lens has to be in the lensfun database.  NASA equipment is not typically available to the general public, so they are unlikely to be added to the database.
- [lenscorrection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection): You need to calculate *k1* and *k2*, based on this equation:

  ```
  r_src = r_tgt * (1 + k1 * (r_tgt / r_0)^2 + k2 * (r_tgt / r_0)^4)
  ```

  Other parameters, like *cx* and *cy*, can be assumed.  There is an OpenCV [camera calibration example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) that calculates the parameters from photos of recognized targets (eg, chessboard pattern).  Then you would plug the values into the command:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i in-file -vf "lenscorrection=cx=0.5:cy=0.5:k1=[]:k2=[]" out-file
  ```

  Unless NASA has taken and released calibration images, this approach is unlikely to work.

  See also:

  - Video Production: [Correct lens distortion with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/correct-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg)
  - StackOverflow: [Is there a way to remove GoPro fisheye using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832248/is-there-a-way-to-remove-gopro-fisheye-using-ffmpeg)

Other tools to consider:

- [Hugin](https://www.hugin.com/): Can calculate and apply lens correction parameters.  Cannot be used to find *k1* and *k2* because it uses a different lens correction model.  Will apply generic corrections that may be good enough if lens specifications are known (or guessed).
- Photoshop: [Adaptive Wide Angle Filter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adaptive-wide-angle-filter.html)
- RawTherapee, and other raw processing applications: Usually include a distortion correction tool with parameters you can tweak for a good-enough approximation.

---

Note: Some images released by NASA may already be corrected for distortion.

[image: NASA image]

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately not helping so much.

Comment: You need *k1, k2* parameters.  To compute them, you need calibration images.  Since people outside of NASA usually don't have access to their equipment, you should contact NASA for further assistance.